# Get distinct groups of id's with overlapping values

Tags: sql-server

Spinning my wheels on this. Trying to get unique group-sets based on overlapping id's and the association of the data. I'll explain through my example a little more clearly:

```
with src as (
    select [hash], id, 
        -- determine uniqueness of the hash by rank()
        rank() over (partition by [hash] order by id) rnk
    from ( 
        -- mocked data
        values
        ('0x00', '1000'),
        ('0x0A', '1001'), 
        ('0x0A', '1002'),
        ('0x0B', '1001'), 
        ('0x0B', '1002'),
        ('0x0B', '1003'),
        ('0x0C', '3001'),
        ('0x0C', '3002'),
        ('0x0C', '3003'),
        ('0x0D', '3001'),
        ('0x0D', '3002'),
        ('0x0D', '3003')
    ) as t([hash], id)
),
filter as (
    -- filters out any id's with no overlapping hashes
    select distinct [hash], id
    from src s
    where exists (
        select 1 from src t
        where s.[hash] = t.[hash]
        and t.rnk > 1
    )
)
```

Then I need to determine all the id's grouped by hash. So a set of data resembles something like this I'm assuming:

```
0x0A: 1001, 1002
0x0B: 1001, 1002, 1003
0x0C: 3001, 3002, 3003
0x0D: 3001, 3002, 3003
```

Then from that set above determine unique combinations by association. By association I mean since the set 1001, 1002 are part of the set 1001, 1002, and 1003, I want to combine them into a unique set of 1001, 1002, 1003. Hash is discarded at this point.

Looking for a final output of something like this:

```
groupsetid  id
1           1001
1           1002
1           1003
2           3001
2           3002
2           3003
```

Or this if easier:

```
groupsetid  ids
1           1001, 1002, 1003
2           3001, 3002, 3003
```

This is ultimately a report to tell us what id's conflict with each other for a given x amount of overlapping hashes. Thanks so much in advanced to anyone who wants to take a crack at this, I'm going nuts trying to figure it out!

EDIT: This just a test case, these are not the actual values I'm dealing with, just a representation of the data and some of the combinations seen. Therefore I can't use logic filtering the values themselves using like operators, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id 
,GroupIds = case when id like '1%' then '1' when id like '3%' then '3' else 'N/A' end
from src
group by 
id
```

Does this do it for you. You will add the above lines after your src CTE.

Comment: i take it this is a test case. You will really need to maintain a lookup table of some kind where you can quickly match the case values; esp if its for a report.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is just a test case.

Comment: then perhaps your first cte will be a lookup for those groupIDs if its few hundred or thousand rows you probly wont need an filter but if its more I suggest you may. By lookup I mean here a table where you can quickly match up values and render for report. In this lookup you will store your final desired result.